# How can I get AWS lambda usage for the last hour?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I would like to know if there is a way to get all of my lambda invocation usages for the last 1 hour (better if every 5 minutes).
It could also be nice to get the cost usage (but from what I've read it only updates once a day).

From looking at the documentation it seems like I can use `GetMetricData` (Cloudwatch), is there a better one for my use case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get this information by region within CloudWatch metrics.

In the `AWS/Lambda` namespace is a metric named `Invocations`, this can be viewed for the entire region or on a per Lambda basis.

If you look at the Sum per whichever period you want to use (you can get down to per 1 minute values for this metric), you will be able to get these values in near real-time.

You can get these values from within the console or by using the [get-metric-data](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/cloudwatch/get-metric-data.html) command within the CLI or SDK.

Comment: Can I include with it cost/estimation of cost? and does it have instance type/invocation time?

Comment: There is another metric of (Duration), however no metrics for cost. If you want to get these you would need to use cost explorer. Cost explorer does support hourly billing bu tat a cost: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/11/aws-cost-explorer-supports-hourly-resource-level-granularity/

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look :)

Answer (score 0):

There are many tools to get metrics on your lambda, so it really depends on your needs.
What do you mean by "is there a better one for my use case"?

If you prefer, you can check it through the console: Go to cloudwatch -> metrics -> and navigate to your lambda. You can aggregate the data differently (examples: average per 5 minutes, or total a day, etc.)

Here's a great doc: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/monitoring-metrics.html#monitoring-metrics-invocation

Moreover, here's a solution that I gave that surveys different approaches to monitor lambda resources: [Best Way to Monitor Customer Usage of AWS Lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64626502/best-way-to-monitor-customer-usage-of-aws-lambda/64633897#64633897)

Disclosoure: I work for Lumigo, a company that does exactly that.