# AWS API to get the lambda invocation history

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I can see the most recent invocations for lambda in the AWS console UI but I was wondering if there is any API to get a particular lambda (by arn or name) invocation history. The only way I can think of is identifying through cloudwatch logs. Any advice on this?

Comment: Either cloudwatch or cloudtrail if enabled, there is nothing built-in for this.

Comment: Hey, I think that you will find an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64626502/best-way-to-monitor-customer-usage-of-aws-lambda/64633897#64633897

Answer (score 1):

**AWS CloudTrail** records API calls made to services.

**Amazon CloudWatch Logs** keeps logs for each Lambda invocation, including error messages.

However, you would probably fine **Amazon CloudWatch Metrics** to be the most useful. For every function, it records Invocations, Errors, Duration, Throttles, etc. You can view these metrics in the management console, or retrieve them from CloudWatch via API calls. They are the same metrics shown in the AWS Lambda console in the "Monitoring" tab for a function.

Comment: Hi John, thanks for the response! Please correct me if I am wrong but it shows the metrics but not the execution ID for those items right? I am trying to get the execution ID for the lambdas.

Comment: Amazon CloudWatch Metrics goes down to the **Function Name**, so you can look at the the sum of invocations over a period of time. However, if you are are looking for the exact time that a function was run, then CloudWatch Logs will show every execution (including the Execution ID). CloudTrail should also contain an entry for each execution, but might not contain the Execution ID and would have a lot of non-Lambda entries you would need to ignore, so using CloudWatch Logs would be better.

Answer (score -1):

I think that a good starting point is troubleshooting tools. There are a few 3rd party tools that can give you the ability to see the invocations history, as long as dive in into each invocation (what was the event, the outgoing calls etc.).

Disclosour: I'm working in Lumigo, and we're doing exactly that, but also let you consider each invocation in a broader "transaction" view (the triggered services from this lambda). Here's an example screenshot that fits to your problem:
[image]

Comment: You could have mentioned how this data is derived instead of only promoting your service.